# Does caml-mode indent comments?

Tags: emacs, indentation, ml

I am editing `.ml` code under `Emacs`. My default mode is `caml-mode`.

I realize that `Tab` on a line or `M-x indent-region` on a region does not adjust the place of a comment, whereas `tuareg-mode` does so.

Doesn't `caml-mode` indent comments by nature? Is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A look at the source code reveals, that `caml-mode` does not indent comments at all.  The root cause is in [`caml-compute-final-indent` in `caml.el`](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/blob/18962fdd15a6371de6e62d4c32bb761642d3fb4a/emacs/caml.el#L1635):

```
(defun caml-compute-final-indent ()
  (save-excursion
    (back-to-indentation)
    (cond
     ((and (bolp) (looking-at comment-start-skip)) (current-column))
     ((caml-in-comment-p)
      (let ((closing (looking-at "\\*)"))
            (comment-mark (looking-at "\\*")))
        (caml-backward-comment)
        (looking-at comment-start-skip)
        (+ (current-column)
           (cond
            (closing 1)
            (comment-mark 1)
            (t (- (match-end 0) (match-beginning 0)))))))
     (t (let* ((leading (looking-at caml-leading-kwops-regexp))
               (assoc-val (if leading (assoc (caml-match-string 0)
                                             caml-leading-kwops-alist)))
               (extra (if leading (symbol-value (nth 1 assoc-val)) 0))
               (prio (if leading (nth 2 assoc-val)
                       caml-max-indent-priority))
               (basic (caml-compute-basic-indent prio)))
          (max 0 (if extra (+ extra basic) (current-column))))))))
```

This function computes the indentation offset of the line at point.  The first branch in the `cond` expression handles the beginning of a comment, and simply returns the original indentation offset unchanged.

To fix this, you would have to re-implement or advise `caml-compute-final-indent`.  Probably—I am not sure and have not tested it— it is sufficient to copy the whole implementation to your `init.el`, and simply remove the first `cond` branch completely.  In this case, indentation would be handled by the last branch, which computes the indentation offset for expressions.  This may, or more likely may not work.

From what I have seen in the source code, I'd advise against `caml-mode`.  The code is outdated, and does not follow many conventions mandatory for modern Emacs modes, nor does it use features provided by modern Emacs versions to deal with indentation.  It is [not really actively maintained](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/blob/trunk/emacs/caml.el), most recent changes are minor bugs, or formatting fixes.  All major contributions happened at least five years ago.

Really use `tuareg-mode`, at best from MELPA which provides latest snapshot from the `tuareg-mode` SVN.  The development of `tuareg-mode` is somewhat drowsy, too, but there [are at least some major changes with the last two years](https://forge.ocamlcore.org/scm/browser.php?group_id=43).